# How to fix "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types" when multiply two values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sql-update, multiplication

When click on update button, it does'n update both quantity and his price only updated quantity.It shows fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types on line where multiply the quantity and price_value. Thank u

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="size_id[]" value="<?php echo $size_id_2; ?>">
<input name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" type="number" id="number" >
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

      $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
      $size_id = $_POST['size_id'];
      $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
      $price_value = $_POST['price'];

      $updated_price = $price_value * $quantity;

      foreach($product_id as $index => $h){
      $v = $size_id[$index];
      $q = $quantity[$index];
      $p = $updated_price[$index];
      $update_query = "UPDATE cart SET product_price='$p',quantity='$q' WHERE product_id='$h' AND size_id='$v'";
      $run_query = mysqli_query($con , $update_query);

      if($run_query){
        echo"<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
            }
          }
        }

    ?>      
<button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-icon btn-icon-left btn-primary btn-shape-circle offset-top-35"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Update Cart</button>
</form>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) the string is not safe!

Comment: really, Oh My GOD. i really dont no about the SQL injection Attacks, very helpful for me.Thanks

Comment: But my problem can't solve, still

Comment: give me some solution, i m badly stuck

Comment: What are the types of price_value and quantity

Comment: The names of your form elements like `name="price[]"` means that those values will be arrays in `$_POST`. (You can't multiply something by an array.) You need to remove the square brackets from the name so you'll have single values.

Comment: First get these values from cart table and than quantity type  is "number" and price type="hidden". both values are multiply and updated in cart table.

Comment: we have multiple values and only one update button to updated all the values so thats way i m using this square brackets to become an array and than use foreach loop to get these array

Comment: I see. But your calculation is outside the foreach loop.

Comment: i know, give me some better solution. i dont no how to fix this thats way i am here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
<input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="size_id[]" value="<?php echo $size_id_2; ?>">
<input name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" type="number" id="number" >
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
<?php

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

  $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
  $size_id = $_POST['size_id'];
  $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
  $price_value = $_POST['price'];

      $total_price = array($price_value);

      $values_multiple = array_sum($total_price);

      foreach($product_id as $index => $h){

      $v = $size_id[$index];
      $q = $quantity[$index];
      $p  = $price_value[$index]; 

      $values_multiple = $q * $p;

      $total_grand = $values_multiple;

    $update_query = "UPDATE cart SET product_price='$total_grand',quantity='$q' WHERE product_id='$h' AND size_id='$v'";
      $run_query = mysqli_query($con , $update_query);

      if($run_query){
        echo"<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
            }

          }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: Is there explanation that could be added to this? So it might be helpful to others?